# ModuleNotFoundError when run in IDLE, no error however when run in cmd

Tags: python

So the question is as stated above. When i run little script which relies on matplotlib and numpy, both of which I have installed and listed when entering help("modules"), by simply double-clicking on it, it works fine, but if i open it with the IDLE first and then run it in the Shell it doesn't. Why is that? I know that pip did install the packages in a directory outside of PATH, but I added it to it once i got this error message, but it still doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated, you would really make a beginners day. I can provide code if necessary, but I think this is most certainly not the problem.

Comment: Did you import them in the IDLE ? they should not just be installed, you nede to import module in each file/terminal you use them

Comment: Worth checking if you have more than one Python installed on your machine.

Comment: Can you tell us which instructions did you follow? I had a similar issue when using git bash to run python scripts, but I don't know if my answer could help you, so I prefer to ask you before telling you something useless.

Comment: In both IDLE and the command line try running `import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.path)` to make sure a) you are running the same Python interpreter, and b) they have the same module paths. In general you should not have to mess with paths manually and *shouldn't* unless you know exactly what you are doing.